# "a machine-gun speed" vs "a machine-gun's speed"

Tags: vocabulary, attributive-nouns

*He speaks with a machine-gun speed.*
"He speaks with a machine-gun's speed".

The second one seems less standard.

But I also feel that we would say "he runs at a car's speed" not "car speed"

And shouldn't we change "with" to "at" since we're dealing with speed? Moreover, could we make do without the article in the top sentences?

Also, if you have some interesting way to say this please share.

Comment: Check your spelling.  (Machine)

Comment: "He runs at car speed" or "He runs at a car's speed", but not "He runs at a car speed". Also, one notable difference between the firing rate of a machine gun and the driving speed of a car is that the rate for the machine gun is relatively constant (300bullets to 1000 bullets per minute), whereas the speed of a car is highly variable, varying from 10km/h to 200km/h, so "machine gun speed" is kind of a defined quantity, whereas "car speed" is not. "A car's speed" is more vague (we're not specifying which car) so it's more appropriate.

Comment: Also "speed" suggests it's the speed of the bullet. "rate" would be more accurate if you want the number of bullets per minute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

'Machine gun'(check your spelling, by the way) is a compound noun, but we can use almost any noun (including compound nouns) as an *adjective*. That is the case in your example sentence.

'*He speaks with a machine gun speed*' is not about a literal machine gun's speed. 'Speed' is not a quality of a machine gun. This statement is about the speed at which someone speaks, and is using 'machine gun' as an adjective to describe the speed of his speech. Machine guns are known for being able to fire rapidly without a break, so it is metaphorically describing a person's speech as having similar rapid, relentless qualities.

You are quite right that, if you were speaking about the literal speed of a real machine gun, you would say "a machine gun's speed", or "the speed of a machine gun". Although, I'm not sure that would be idiomatic in the literal sense. You'd normally talk about the *rate of fire* of a gun rather than its 'speed'.

Answer (score 9):

Saying "at machine-gun speed" seems better.  "Speed" is uncountable, and if "machine-gun" is used attributively, it doesn't get an article.  The preposition "at" collocates with an indication of speed in expressions like "going at 100mph"

Simpler might just be the simile: "He talks like a machine gun."

Comment: I would prefer 'he spoke at machine-gun rate'.

Comment: Perhaps.  I'm not overly fond of the analogy anyway.

Answer (score 7):

We *don't* normally include the article before an attributive noun like "***machine gun***" in the OP's example.

We're actually more likely to use the preposition "***at***" rather than "***with***" in the given context. And we're more likely *not* to hyphenate "***machine gun***" (which surprised me - I got no results at all for my chart until I realised that and changed my search terms). Anyway, [here's the chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20a%20machine%20gun%20speed%2Cat%20machine%20gun%20speed%2Cwith%20a%20machine%20gun%20speed%2Cwith%20machine%20gun%20speed&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]

---

We wouldn't normally say "*he runs at a car's speed*" - it would be "*he runs **at the speed of** a car*". But that's obviously a metaphorical exaggeration anyway, and it's *not* a "standard" metaphor. The idiomatic standard is "*...at the speed of a **cheetah***" (but what we actually say is "*he runs **like** a cheetah*").

Comment: Just for clarity, the phrasing your first paragraph suggests is "He speaks with machine gun speed", dropping the "a".  That sounds the best to me, with "He speaks with the speed of a machine gun" about equally good in terms of grammar.

Comment: I hope my first paragraph does more than "suggest" dropping the "a". Sure - it's "syntactically valid" either way, but we almost *never* include the article in this context. Also note the red arrow on the chart, pointing to the words *Ngrams not found: **at A machine gun speed, with A machine gun speed***. The usage with article is too rare to show on the chart!